# Regex expression to match the first digit of a string with 4.

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a credit card validation Java program and I am stuck on how to format a regex expression properly to check if the CC number starts with 4. 
This is what I have:

```
if (cardNum.matches("^4\\d"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String#matches` function applies the pattern you specify to the *entire* string input.  So the following might be what you have in mind:

```
if (cardNum.matches("^4\\d+")) {
    // then CC starts with 4, followed by more numbers
}
```

But note that the problem of creating regular expressions to validate various types of credit card numbers is an old one, and has already been solved.  Have a look [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your regex will only match the string "4\d." If you wanted it to mean "4, and then 0 or more decimals", you should use the Kleene star operator "*" like so `4\d*`

Comment: This is right, but the exact reason for this is that `String#matches` checks the entire input, and not just a portion of it.

Comment: Right, this is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are matching the **whole** Credit Card number and you are using `s.matches()`.

And as you can see [matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) is actually checking the **whole** string that is invoking the method:

> Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.

And also it mentions:

> An invocation of this method of the form str.matches(regex) yields exactly the same result as the expression: `Pattern.matches(regex, str)`

So the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) provides details about how the `regex` works.

> \d => A digit: [0-9]
>
> ^  => The beginning of a line
>
> X+ => X, one or more times

In your case, you need to ensure the **regex pattern** match the **whole** credit card number.

```
if (cardNum.matches("^4\\d+"));
```

If you need to specify the length range to eliminate invalid numbers:

> X{n,m}    => X, at least n but not more than m times

You need to specify it as:

```
if (cardNum.matches("^4\\d{16,19}"));
```

If you are checking lots of the numbers, you'd better turn to `Pattern` instead to avoid [senseless pattern compiling overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469244/whats-the-difference-between-string-matches-and-matcher-matches) as:

```
private final static Pattern CREDIT_CARD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^4\\d+");
if (CREDIT_CARD_PATTERN.matcher(s).matches());
```

When it contains **hyphens** or **whitespaces**, you can use the `regex` as:

1. `"^4\\d{3}-\\d{4}-\\d{4}-\\d{3}"` to match `4485-7622-4840-4312`;
2. `^4\\d{3}\s*\\d{4}\\s*\\d{4}\\s*\\d{4}` to match `4485762248404312` and `4485 7622 4840 4312`;