# String.matches() and matcher.matches() return different results

Tags: java

In the following code sample, matcher.matches() and String.matches do not return the same result and I don't understand why :

```
    String MIDDLESIGN = "[(\\/)"+"|"+"(\\*)"+"|"+"(\\++)"+"|"+"(\\-+)]";
    String x = "1 +++ 2 * 3 -- 4";
    System.out.println("1 +++ 2 * 3 -- 4".matches("(\\d+\\s+"+MIDDLESIGN+"*"+"\\s+\\d*)+")); //true

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile((\\d+\\s+"+MIDDLESIGN+"*"+"\\s+\\d*)+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);

    System.out.println(matcher.matches()); //false
```

Any idea why this difference ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between String.matches and Matcher.matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469244/whats-the-difference-between-string-matches-and-matcher-matches)

Comment: This is already addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469244/whats-the-difference-between-string-matches-and-matcher-matches)

Comment: Look at this answer to understand why both returns the same result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2469287/8112679

Comment: @momodjib What is value of MIDDLESIGN??

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi, in my case I get different results from both so it won't help me

Comment: @SumitSingh we have the same MIDDLESIGN in both case so it should not matter but I edited the post to include it.

Comment: *FYI:* When removing Java escapes and string concatenations, the `MIDDLESIGN` regex is `[(\/)|(\*)|(\++)|(\-+)]` which is a single character class that will match exactly *one* of the following characters: `( ) + - * / |`. The rest are just unnecessary escapes and redundant duplicates. You seem to expect it to mean something else, so reevaluate what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like issue in your code:

Its working fine: [result](https://paiza.io/projects/brIJ8MV7naAMSOgtKXekng?language=java)

```
String MIDDLESIGN = "[(\\/)"+"|"+"(\\*)"+"|"+"(\\++)"+"|"+"(\\-+)]";
String x = "1 +++ 2 * 3 -- 4";
System.out.println("1 +++ 2 * 3 -- 4".matches("(\\d+\\s+" + MIDDLESIGN + "*" + "\\s+\\d*)+")); // true

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\s+" + MIDDLESIGN + "*" + "\\s+\\d*)+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);
System.out.println(matcher.matches()); // true
```

From you code:
Pattern.compile(**(\d+\s+"+MIDDLESIGN+"*"+"\s+\d*)+"**);

there is missing `"` in it. replace it with below code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\s+" + MIDDLESIGN + "*" + "\\s+\\d*)+");
```