# How to validate user input to only allow numbers

Tags: c#

I have a method here that allows the user to enter any number except for 999. But I don't know how to create a validation when user enters a negative number or letter.

```
    static int EnterScores(double[] scores, int maxScores)
    {
        double userInput;           
        int count = 0;
        while (count < maxScores)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a score(or 999 to quit): ");
            userInput = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (userInput == 999 || userInput < 0)
                break;
            scores[count++] = userInput;       
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: You already have a check with `userInput < 0`. What is the problem you have?

Comment: Sorry I should've said creating a error message for whenever user inputs negative number or a letter

Comment: When `maxScores` is larger than the array's length you'll get an index out of range exception. It also seems arbitrary, that the user can enter `1000` or larger but `999` ends it.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607260/check-non-numeric-characters-in-string for how to check for non-numeric characters.  Once you have a string with no non-numeric characters, you can check for <999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user inputs a letter or something that can't be converted to `double` your this piece of code `double.TryParse` will throw an `exception` and program will fail.

So you should use `try-catch` block here:

```
try
{
    userInput = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (userInput == 999)
    {
        break;
    }
    else if (userInput < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
    } 
    else
    {
        scores[count++] = userInput;
    }
}
catch(Exception e)  // will take care of letters
{
    Console.WriteLine("You enter an Invalid input !"):
}
```

Comment: In the catch statement, how does "Exception e" takes care of letters?

Comment: Just place this code and enter a letter and you'll see how this take care of letters

Comment: The `e` is not actually required, since you're not using it. Just `catch (Exception) { }` works.

Comment: @Blorgbeard it is required ... otherwise it will throw error `<identifier> expected`.

Comment: Actually you don't really even need the `Exception`, you can just do `catch { }` to catch all exceptions.

Comment: yeah this can be done but saying you don't need to add ta name of `object` like `e` is wrong. But this is acceptable i think however i'll try it on my machine

Comment: It's a special case for catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2). If it can convert string to float - it will be `true`

```cs
...
var str = Console.ReadLine();
if (double.TryParse(str, out userInput)){
    if (userInput == 999 || userInput < 0)
        break;
    scores[count++] = userInput;
}
...
```

Comment: I tried that before. The problem is that the Console.Write("Enter a score(or 999 to quit): "); has to read continuously. With the code, you linked I have to press enter to input.

Comment: @SH093 try add `else` to this `if`. Like `if (double.TryParse(...)) { ... } else { break; }`

Comment: ok, that fixes the first problem. My main issue is still giving me an error whenever I input a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the tests for `userInput` == 999 and `userInput` < 0, like this:

```
...
if (userInput == 999)
{
    break;
}
else if (userInput < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
} 
else
{
    scores[count++] = userInput;
}
...
```

Comment: This works but then what about the letter validation?

Comment: In this case, use `double.TryParse` as suggested by @vic_78 in his answer. If the result is `false`, it means the input was not a value that can be converted to a double, in which case you can display the "invalid input" error message.