# Application Translation String Resource Expense & Pattern Compiling

Tags: java, android

Having made the mistake of not constructing my application to be translation friendly from outset, I'm now amidst the arduous process of retrospectively doing so...

My application involves the recognition of speech and therefore language variances are common within the code itself, rather than just in the layout and description which is perhaps more common.

I'm therefore maybe more concerned than most about the performance cost of using XML String resources and weighing this up again the massive effort of writing new code/classes for each language.

Here is an example Class which I hope with a little imagination will give you an idea of my quandary:

```
private static Pattern pWIFI = Pattern.compile(".*\\bwifi\\b.*");
private static Pattern pMOBD = Pattern.compile(".*\\bdata\\b.*");
private static Pattern pBLUE = Pattern.compile(".*\\bbluetooth\\b.*");
private static Pattern pAIRPLANE = Pattern.compile(".*\\bairplane\\b.*");
private static Pattern pAEROPLANE = Pattern.compile(".*\\baeroplane\\b.*");


public class MatchingAndReplacingStuff {

        for (String vd : voiceData) {

            vd = vd.toLowerCase(loc).trim();

            if (vd.startsWith(ctx.getString(R.string.KEYBOARD_)) || vd.startsWith(ctx.getString(R.string.KEY_BOARD_))
                    || vd.startsWith(ctx.getString(R.string.KEYBOARDS_))
                    || vd.startsWith(ctx.getString(R.string.KEY_BOARDS_)) || vd.startsWith(ctx.getString(R.string.KEYBORD_))
                    || vd.startsWith(ctx.getString(R.string.KEYBORDS_))) {

                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.KEYBOARDS_), "");
                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.KEYBOARD_), "");
                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.KEY_BOARD_), "");
                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.KEY_BOARDS_), "");
                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.KEYBORD_), "");
                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.KEYBORDS_), "");

                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.GOOGLE_VOICE_TYPING), ctx.getString(R.string.GOOGLE_SEARCH));
                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.VOICE_TYPING), ctx.getString(R.string.GOOGLE_SEARCH));
                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.VOICE_INPUT), ctx.getString(R.string.GOOGLE_SEARCH));
                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.VOICE_KEYBOARD), ctx.getString(R.string.GOOGLE_SEARCH));
                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.VOICE_KEYBORD), ctx.getString(R.string.GOOGLE_SEARCH));
                vd = vd.replaceFirst(ctx.getString(R.string.VOICE_KEY_BOARD), ctx.getString(R.string.GOOGLE_SEARCH));

                voiceDataUpdated.add(vd.trim());

                    }
                }

    // loop again and compare Strings in voiceDataUpdated to Patterns compiled above

        }
```

Under the assumption that Bluetooth and WiFi and every other R.String above is different in each language, the following performance/correctness/translations question arise for me:

1) Should each `ctx.getString(R.string` be assigned to a String prior to the loops? The maximum number of voice data strings would be around 30 - So is performance even worth considering? For others reading this question in the future, is there a threshold at which it should be considered?

2) As a Context would be required to compile the Patterns (when getting the String resource), is a variation of the following even possible?

```
Pattern.compile(".*\\bctx.getString(R.string.SOMETHING\\b.*"); <-- pseudo code
```

3) If the answer to question 2 is no, but Patterns can be compiled in such a way, should I compile them, or just build a String to compare instead - or not even bother?!

The final question would be: As I'm dealing with looping through String Arrays that have at the most 300 entries, should I just completely forget performance (within reason)!?

^ I like to think that when constructing my code, I find a happy medium between readability and performance, but if I was to forget performance (due to the above only and the limited size of my loops), I'd really need a few people to assure me it's the right thing to do!!

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Should each `ctx.getString(R.string...)` be assigned to a String prior to the loops? The maximum number of voice data strings would be around 30 - So is performance even worth considering? For others reading this question in the future, is there a threshold at which it should be considered?

Yes, if your strings are reused, otherwise there is no need to. There is no threshold, there is only possible optimization according to your use-case.

> As a Context would be required to compile the Patterns (when getting the String resource), is a variation of the following even possible?

```
Pattern.compile(".*\\bctx.getString(R.string.SOMETHING)\\b.*");
```

No, you cannot use it this way, I'd considered creating and compiling patterns in class constructor.

> If the answer to question 2 is no, but Patterns can be compiled in such a way, should I compile them, or just build a String to compare instead - or not even bother?!

Patterns cannot be compiled in such way, you cannot use method call as a string within pattern definition.

Answer is taken from: [java.util.regex - importance of Pattern.compile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720191/java-util-regex-importance-of-pattern-compile)

> **Compile parses the regular expression and builds an in-memory representation. The overhead to compile is significant compared to a match. So if you're using a pattern repeatedly it will gain some performance to cache the compiled pattern.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say a 'class constructor', most of my Classes consists of public static methods which I call directly. Could you elaborate under these circumstances please? If that's possible of course.

Comment: Eh, you cannot use `getString()` as it connects to Context, so only option is to use some Constructor which takes `Context` argument and resolves strings according to current resource resolver.