# parsing strings with or without regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying create a basic file system to imitate the terminal. I am currently stuck on getting the names after the command. My first thought was to use regex to parse the commands.

Examples of commands would be:

```
mkdir hello
ls
cd hello
```

However to account for many whitespaces an input could be `mkdir       hello`. I was wondering if there is another way without using regex? Also I was curious to which method is faster? With or without regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try splitting the lines like

```
String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
```

And for basic commands, most likely your command will be at `tokens[0]` followed by arguments.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that is most helpful to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(String current: line.split("\\s+"){
   //do something.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, regex is faster because you can compile it.

see [java.util.regex - importance of Pattern.compile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720191/java-util-regex-importance-of-pattern-compile)

(Internally, I think the JVM always compile the regex at some point, but if you do it explicitly, you can reuse it. I am not sure if the JVM is smart enough to reuse a compiled regex locally, maybe it is)