# String replacement efficiency java

Tags: java, regex, replace

Which way is more efficient to replace characters/substring in a string. I have searched and i have found two ways :

```
output = output.replaceAll(REGEX, REPLACEMENT);
```

or

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher m = p.matcher(output);
output = m.replaceAll(REPLACEMENT);
```

I mean with efficiency : less time, loops and/or new variables.

Comment: See [java.util.regex - importance of Pattern.compile()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720191/java-util-regex-importance-of-pattern-compile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the String method `replaceAll` it does the same under the hood:

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement);
}
```

If you want to use the same pattern multiple times. It's better to go with the second option as you will not need to recompile it every time.