# How to serialize a java.util.regex.Pattern using protobuf?

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I have an object that I want to serialize using Protocol Buffers and store in redis. The object contains a `java.util.regex.Pattern` that is complied when the object is instantiated.

```
public class SerializableEntity {
    private Pattern pattern;
    private List<String> options;
}
```

This pattern is used to validate inputs to a certain api. Since compiling the pattern each time is [expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1721778), I'm compiling the pattern once during instantiation and then reusing the same pattern instance each time the api is invoked. How do I serialize this compile `Pattern` field in the following schema so I when I de-serialize the object, I can use it without compiling the pattern again?

```
 message SerializableEntityProto {
     repeated string option = 1;
     // compiled pattern
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Store [`pattern.pattern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#pattern--)? (and `pattern.flags()`, if you might compile it with non-default flags).

Comment: @AndyTurner so this has to be compiled each time I retrieve it from redis?

Comment: You probably want some lazy initialization for the pattern. Read it only once from redis on first access, compile the pattern string and use the compiled pattern. Check [lazy initialization on demand holder idom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom)

Comment: @dpr I'm reading it from redis each time the api is invoked and i need to perform some regex operation. it's not possible to store this locally.

Comment: Actually `Pattern` implements `Serializable`, that is you could rely on Java's (de)serialization. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array Maybe convert it to base64 and store the string in redis. But I don't see why you would want to use protobufs for this.

Comment: Have you considered a static `Pattern`? Serialization looks like massive overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.regex.Pattern` does not have encode and decode proto functions implemented in itself. However, you can implement that yourself pretty easy (as Andy Turner suggests). Something like this:

Proto

```
syntax = "proto2";

package termin4t0r;
option java_package = "com.example.termin4t0r";

// Proto for java.util.regex.Pattern
message RegexPatternProto {
  // See Pattern.pattern()
  optional string pattern = 1;
  // See Pattern.flags()
  optional int64 flags = 2;
}
```

Java encode and decode functions

```
class RegexpPatternProtos {
  public static RegexPatternProto encode(java.util.regex.Pattern pattern) {
    return RegexPatternProto.newBuilder()
        .setPattern(pattern.pattern())
        .setFlags(pattern.flags())
        .build();
  }

  public static java.util.regex.Pattern decode(RegexPatternProto patternProto) {
    return new RegexPatternProto(
      patternProto.getPattern(), patternProto.getFlags());
  }
}
```

I leave the unittests as an exercise :) I even find serializing this way preferable as protocol buffers have forward and backward compatibility, whereas java serialization has problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of square peg and round hole, protobuf and serialization is not meant to be used that way.

Anyway it seems like you initialize a regex with every API call. I don't know how your app decides which Regex to use for a particular API, but you must start out with a Regex string to compile. 
Instead of trying to serializing the pattern, store it in memory in a `HashMap<String,Pattern>`( Regex string as a key and the compiled pattern as value). And then get the pattern when you need it.